# GetDataRow returns null for valid rowHandle

Tags: c#, event-handling, devexpress-gridcontrol

I am trying to get the selected rows from a grid, when the user selects an option from a popup menu.
I have the following code

```
    private void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, 
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.MenuType != DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMenuType.Row) return;
        var item = new DXMenuItem("Delete");
        item.Click += (o, args) =>
        {
            var rowHandles = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
            foreach (var rowHandle in rowHandles)
            {
                System.Data.DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(rowHandle); 
                // debugger shows that rowHandle = 1 
                if (row == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("how so?");  // breaks here
                }
            }
        };
        e.Menu.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

When I run in the debugger I would expect the row to be valid, however it is null.

Comment: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetDataRow.method

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that since I have the grid getting data from a bindingsource and I am setting the bindingsource

[the docs explain](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetDataRow.method) that GetDataRows will return null

> If the View's data source is a custom collection of objects, the GetDataRow method returns null